# "unreachable code" after select statement in a Go program

Tags: go, select, channel, unreachable-code

I am playing with channels and don't quite understand why the code I wrote becomes unreachable at this point and also a deadlock arises. Shouldn't the select take the value from the quit channel and then exit from the infinite for loop?

```
func run(jobs []Job, receive, quit chan int) {
    for _, job := range jobs {
        go func(job Job) {
            receive <- longCalculation(job)
        }(job)
    }
    quit <- -1 // write to the channel to signal end of work
}

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    jobs := makeJobs()
    receive := make(chan int)
    quit := make(chan int)

    run(jobs, receive, quit)

    var sum int
    for {
        select {
        case data := <-receive:
            sum += data
        case <-quit: // take the last value indicating end of work
            fmt.Println("Exiting for loop ...", quit)
            return
        }
    }
    fmt.Print(sum) -> this line says unreachable code
}
```

Comment: The `return` statement does not exit the loop, it exists the enclosing function. So the statement after the `for` loop will never be reached.

Comment: there is a synchronization defect in your code, the send to quit occurs way too soon. End of Work happens when all routines exited, not, when they all got spawned.

Answer (score 1):

```golang
for {
        select {
        case data := <-receive:
            sum += data
        case <-quit: // take the last value indicating end of work
            fmt.Println("Exiting for loop ...", quit)
            return
        }
    }
```

Change it into

```golang
running := true
for running {
        select {
        case data := <-receive:
            sum += data
        case <-quit: // take the last value indicating end of work
            fmt.Println("Exiting for loop ...", quit)
            running = false
            break
        }
    }
```

It's because the function stop immediately when you return

Comment: That won't help: `break` will break from the `select`, not from the `for` loop.

Comment: oops, i forgot it, sorry let me change my answer

Comment: for the deadlock you need to increase quit channel length by 1. or call run with the go keyword.

Comment: @unknownerror try using atomic package?

Answer (score -1):

You can just use a single channel & close it to signal you are done:

```
func run(jobs []Job, receive chan int) {

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(len(jobs))

    for _, job := range jobs {
        go func(job Job) {
            defer wg.Done()

            receive <- longCalculation(job)
        }(job)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    close(receive)
}
```

This simplifies your read-side logic:

```
func main() {

    // ....

    go run(jobs, receive)

    var sum int

    for data := range receive {
        sum += data
    }

    fmt.Print(sum)
}
```